# Cokernel of the injection into double dual

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and let $F$ be a torsion free coherent sheaf. We then have an injection $F\hookrightarrow F^{\vee\vee}$. Let $C$ be the cokernel of this injection. I believe $C$ is torsion.

I remember a statement saying that $C$ is supported only in codimension $\geq 2$. Is this a true statement? If so, is there a reference?

I am aware of Karl Schwede's note's on reflexive sheaves, but could not find the statement I want.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First, the injection into the double dual is correct only for coherent torsion free sheaves. If $X$ is smooth, the cokernel indeed is supported in codimension $\geq 2$, and follows from the fact that over a dvr such sheaves are free and thus equal to its double dual.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks! I will edit the OP accordingly!

Comment: All these statements are correct and you can find all this material in the book of Okonek Schneider and Spindler.